# Notificação Firebase com Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Saudações! Pois bem, estou desenvolvendo um projeto baseado em Firebase que utiliza de muitas funções provenientes do mesmo, como o Firebase Realtime Database para salvar dados e referenciá-los quando necessário, o Firebase Authentication para login, e até mesmo o Firebase Hosting para a hospedagem do site. Sendo que a principal função do projeto é baseada no Firebase Cloud Message, visto que o objetivo do sistema é solucionar problemas na comunicação entre os condôminos e os funcionários, no caso os porteiros, de um condomínio, já que foi percebido a ocorrência de certas confusões no processo de entrega de encomendas requiridas pelos moradores, que muitas vezes passavam pela portaria e chegavam tardiamente na mão dos moradores ou, às vezes, nem ao menos chegavam até os que fizeram a encomenda.

Sendo assim, uma forma de solucionar o problema mencionado seria implantando um sistema que permitisse ao funcionário enviar de sua estação de trabalho, ou seja, de um site, uma notificação para o morador que estivesse esperando a encomenda, no caso, essa notificação seria recebida pelo aplicativo no celular do morador. Todavia, aí é que está o problema, pois uma vez que o Firebase Hosting suporta apenas páginas estáticas (.html), não posso utilizar, ao menos ao que eu saiba, outra linguagem senão o Javascript para enviar as notificações do site, através de um formulário simples que permita o funcionário passar o titulo e a mensagem em si, para o usuário no aplicativo. Dessa forma, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer com que o Javascript entre em contato com o servidor do Firebase e envie a mensagem através do próprio site, isto é, através de uma função acionada a partir do envio do formulário, para o aplicativo. Uma vez que pesquisei a fundo na documentação do Firebase, mas ainda assim não encontrei outro modo para enviar as notificações que não fosse através do console do Firebase.

Espero ter sido claro e desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Ola aqui esta a documentação referente ao envio de mensagens usando javascript na sua pagina:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message?hl=pt-br
Mas eu recomendo o uso do Firebase Cloud Functions e que tenha um registro no firebase realtime database com os tokens dos usuarios
Aqui esta a documentação para ambiente do Cloud Functions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message?hl=pt-br
Mais sobre o cloud functions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases?hl=pt-br#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens